# Play video with slower playback speed on OS X

Tags: macos, video, video-playback

I have a movie that I shot at 240 frames per second. I'd like to play it back at 24 frames per second on my Mac. How can I do this?

How do I slow down playback to 10% speed for an MP4 file?

Comment: VLC allows you to slow down playback speed. Just press `⌘-` a couple of times. It's not very fine grained though. Does that suffice for your needs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In QuickTime Player option-clicking the forward button increases the speed by 0.1. Clicking the backward button plays videos in reverse though. You can slow down videos by running this in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player" to set rate of document 1 to 0.1
```

Or through a terminal:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "QuickTime Player" to set rate of document 1 to 0.1'
```

---

VLC's playback speed can be changed in smaller increments from the menu bar.

[image]

In the menu, the lowest you can set is 0.25. If you press ⌘- the rate can be set even lower, but only to fixed values of 0.5, 0.33, 0.25, 0.12, 0.06, 0.03 and 0.02.

---

In Movist you can press ⇧⌘← or adjust the slider in the control HUD:

[image]

Movist can reduce the playing speed by half, not more.

Comment: VLC's playback speed, controlled through the menu bar, only goes down to 25%, not 10% as the OP needs it. Movist only goes to 50%. Controlling QuickTime is the only working solution in that case.

Comment: Thanks!  The VLC one worked, I didn't know about the control key.

However, the Quicktime one didn't work.  It claimed that it was running at .1 speed, but in reality it was about .8.  Very odd.